# YAML ignores empty array entries if they are at the end of the array

Tags: perl, yaml

I have a simple code that reads a YAML file and dumps it back out into CSV:

```perl
my @data = YAML::LoadFile(${$testplan_path});
    foreach (@{$data[0]}) {
      print "HERE\n";
      print Dumper $_;
      print "\n";
      # Print each yaml array into a csv
      $csv->print($CSVFILE, $_);
      # Add new line
      print $CSVFILE "\n";
    }
```

This works fine except in the case where the YAML file has empty entries at the end of the array.

```yaml
- [Title                             ,Description   ,Type       ,Data                     ,Owner    ,Milestone   ,Tags            ]
- [gfc200 Testplan                   ,              ,Header     ,1                        ,         ,            ,"ONE,TWO"       ]
- [Design Checks                     ,              ,testplan   ,design_checks.yaml       ,harwhi01 ,            ,                ]
```

The print/dump output from the above 3 lines of YAML are as follows:

```
HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'Title',
          'Description',
          'Type',
          'Data',
          'Owner',
          'Milestone',
          'Tags'
        ];

HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'gfc200 Testplan',
          '',
          'Header',
          '1',
          '',
          '',
          'ONE,TWO'
        ];

HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'Design Checks',
          '',
          'testplan',
          'design_checks.yaml',
          'harwhi01',
          ''
        ];
```

As you can see the first two entries are being interpreted by Perl as expected, but the third line is missing an additional empty string as it should look like:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Design Checks',
          '',
          'testplan',
          'design_checks.yaml',
          'harwhi01',
          '',
          ''
        ];
```

in the csv file this gets outputted as:

```
Title,Description,Type,Data,Owner,Milestone,Tags
"gfc200 Testplan",,Header,1,,,"ONE,TWO"
"Design Checks",,testplan,design_checks.yaml,harwhi01,
```

where it should be:

```
Title,Description,Type,Data,Owner,Milestone,Tags
"gfc200 Testplan",,Header,1,,,"ONE,TWO"
"Design Checks",,testplan,design_checks.yaml,harwhi01,,
```

It's important that the output has a consistent amount of columns per row.

How can I resolve this issue?

`$csv` is the module `use Text::CSV;`, but that's not particularly important. As I've shown in the STDOUT, the yaml interpreter is reading in the yaml files into a data structure and already cutting off the empty entry before its dumped into CSV.

Comment: I get exactly what I expect from your input, one trailing (empty) field. See ikegami's answer

Answer (score 7):

Your YAML doesn't mean what you think it means. `[ a, b, ]` only has two elements. It is identical to `[ a, b ]` since YAML allows elements to have a trailing comma. To fix your error, replace

```yaml
[ ...,                ]
```

with

```yaml
[ ..., ""             ]
```

Comment: Yeah.  Or add another field, `[a, , ]` (or `[a,,]`) (one trailing empty field)

Comment: The data sort of looks like fixed width, but with a comma at the end of the field. It's a weird mix.

Comment: @Bork, It's not fixed-width. The lines aren't single strings.

Comment: Oh this is interesting. Thank you, i didn't realise this is how YAML interprets the trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to configure [YAML](https://metacpan.org/dist/YAML/view/lib/YAML.pod) to preserve empty items, but here is a possible workaround for your specific example.

Read the YAML file, then calculate the maximum number of entries for each array.  For the print out, loop through the YAML again, and add empty items to each array which has fewer than the maximum number of items.  Then print out.

For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util      qw(max);
use YAML            qw();
use Data::Dumper    qw(Dumper);

my $yaml = <<'EOF';
- [Title                             ,Description   ,Type       ,Data                     ,Owner    ,Milestone   ,Tags            ]
- [gfc200 Testplan                   ,              ,Header     ,1                        ,         ,            ,"ONE,TWO"       ]
- [Design Checks                     ,              ,testplan   ,design_checks.yaml       ,harwhi01 ,            ,                ]
EOF

my $max = 0;
my @data = YAML::Load($yaml);
for my $aref (@{ $data[0] }) {
    $max = max($max, scalar @{ $aref });
}

for my $aref (@{ $data[0] }) {
    my @items = @{ $aref };
    push @items, '' if @items < $max;
    print "HERE\n";
    print Dumper(\@items);
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'Title',
          'Description',
          'Type',
          'Data',
          'Owner',
          'Milestone',
          'Tags'
        ];

HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'gfc200 Testplan',
          '',
          'Header',
          '1',
          '',
          '',
          'ONE,TWO'
        ];

HERE
$VAR1 = [
          'Design Checks',
          '',
          'testplan',
          'design_checks.yaml',
          'harwhi01',
          '',
          ''
        ];
```

This approach has limitations and makes many assumptions (like only one empty item, but it can be adapted for many).

I don't know enough about YAML to say whether this is a bug in the module or not.

Answer (score -2):

Going to answer my own post by posting the solution i have implemented for the sake of anyone else that has this rather niche problem. I added these lines of code within my for loop

```perl
      if (0+@{$_} lt 0+@testplan_column_list) {
        push @{$_}, '' x (0+@testplan_column_list - @{$_});
      }
```

where @testplan_column_list is an array of strings for each header: Title, Description, Type etc. Unfortunately this is a workaround rather than some way of forcing the YAML module to not ignore the empty data entries.

In my case, the columns are always the same length, 7 items, but can easily modified by changing the @testplan_column_list

Comment: Why are you using stringwise "less than" for number comparisons? You should use `<` for numbers. That it happens to work for you is a coinscidence. For example, `2 lt 10` is false.

Comment: Also, `'' x $number` is not going to do what you think. It will try to concatenate the empty string with itself. The result will always be the empty string, the same way that 0 + 0 is still 0, no matter how many times you add 0. You can force list context on it by adding parens: `('') x $number`.

Comment: Note that you can assign to the value of the last index in an array to extend (or truncate) it to the length you want. You don't need to do index math: `perl -le '$foo{bar} = [qw(a,b)]; $foo{bar}->$#* = 5; print Dumper(\%foo)' -MData::Dumper=Dumper`

Comment: Thank you @Bork . I'm not super comfortable with Perl so i made a mistake or two here. I appreciate the feedback!